# How do I use an object controller in Ember.js with an API that only returns all objects?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a two page Ember.js application using ember-data to wrap a simple RESTful API.  The main page is a list of products, and the other page is a product details page for one product.  The data is loaded via an API that only has an "index" request, `/api/products`.

The above works fine when navigating the site via the main page, however I'm not sure how best to handle navigating directly to the product details page.  I need ember-data to request all products and keep these products client-side so that as the user navigates the simple site it doesn't make any more requests back to the API for products.  However, the ProductIndexView and ProductIndexController in my application should preferably only see the one record.

Is there a good way to handle this in Ember.js?  I know that I could add a computed property to the controller that filters down the full list and then pass that into the view template.  However, I'd rather the view and controller not know about the full list.

Comment: check this https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/Ember-RC1-Router-Sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest all your routes in a resources that fetches all products.

Something like this:

```
App.Route.map(function() {
  this.resource('products', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('index');
    this.resource('product', { path:'/:product_id'} );
  });
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Product.find({});
  }
});

App.ProductsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('products');
  };
});
```

Use the `products/index` template to display all products.

Use the `product` template to display a product detail.

Notice the `{}` I included in `App.Product.find({})`.  This enforces ember-data to return a promise. This is necessary to make the `product` route wait for all `products` to arrive from the server before being called.

Comment: ah thanks!  I had played around with nesting the routes like that, but didn't realize that you could force `find` to return a promise like that, or that returning a promise would force the nested routes to wait.  I'll give it a try later.  Assuming it works, this is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: Took a little bit and then realized that I was on pre-4 not rc-1.  Works great.